# Non-inertial frame and Newton's First and Second laws

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, inertial-frames, machs-principle

The Newton's First law claim that in the absence of forces, a particle moves with constant velocity $v$.

The Newton's Second Law claims that for any particle of mass $m$, the net force $F$ on the particle is always equal to the mass $m$ times the particle's acceleration.

Ok, but in the book I'm studying classical mechanics the author gave us an example where if we are in a non-inertial frame, with acceleration $a$ pointing for somewhere, then those Laws does not hold for us, because if  there is anything at rest outside the referential, then there is no force acting on it even it has an acceleration with relation to that non-inertial frame. But what is wrong to consider that in that case there is a force acting on that object? Because the object will have an acceleration with relation to the frame. In this case why we does not consider a relative force on that object? So in that case the Newton's law will still hold.

Comment: are you familiar with fictitious (pseudo) forces?

Comment: @BobD I'm not familiar

Comment: "But what is wrong to consider that in that case there is a force acting on that object? " In the case of an accelerating car, are you talking about a force that acts on an object that is at rest in the inertial frame of the road, but appears to be accelerating in the reference frame of the accelerating car?

Comment: @BobD Yeah, Exactly!